# PostBack on page causing long time to get to page_init on new page using chart url

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, page-lifecycle

I have a c# ASP.NET program that takes over 1 minute for the page, b.aspx, to load when clicking on a chart in page a.aspx that opens b.aspx.

I thought it might be my queries in b.apsx, but it turns out they run really quick.  Putting some logging into my code I see that from the time the page/class in b.aspx is instantiated to the time it gets to Page_init is 52 seconds by itself.  It appears that a.aspx which takes 52 seconds to load is performing a PostBack and loading again before I can get to b.aspx.

I have set the following in my chart in a.aspx.

```
Chart.Series[series].LegendPostBackValue = "SomeValue";
Chart.Series[series].LegendUrl = url;
```

In `Chart_Click()` I set a session value so I can reference it in b.aspx.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["value"] = e.PostBackValue;
```

In b.aspx I access the data using

```
String somevariable = HttpContext.Current.Session["value"].ToString();
```

Comment: Do you have any undisplayed exception in the application log file ? Do you have any custom program configured to log errors into a text file per example ?

Comment: What function is called before Page_init, Page_Load ? Haved you debugged?

Comment: As far as I know nothing before page_init.  Here is the interesting thing I notice.  I have a page a.aspx.  It takes 52 seconds to load the data on it.  Clicking on a chart in a.aspx opens tab b.aspx, which is the page that is taking 52 seconds to reach the page_init.  It appears that b.aspx doesn't begin opening until a.aspx completely reloads. If I put a `if(!isPostback)` in a.aspx to not load again after clicking b.aspx loads in less than 2 seconds.  The problem is then I get a blank screen on a.aspx which is not acceptable.  I want to see what was there before I clicked on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The page took a long time to reach page_init because it had to reload the calling page due to postback before loading the new page.  The reload was caused by LegendPostBackValue.

a.aspx, the page clicked on to get to b.aspx had a `LegendPostBackValue` set.  This would cause a reload of a.aspx taking an additional 52 seconds.  Removing

```
Chart.Series[series].LegendPostBackValue = "SomeValue";
```

and removing setting a session value in `Chart_Click`

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["value"] = e.PostBackValue;
```

and instead using

```
Chart.Series[series].LegendUrl = url + "?value="SomeValue";
```

and on page b.apsx use

```
String somevariable = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["value"];
```

instead of

```
String somevariable = HttpContext.Current.Session["value"].ToString();
```

fixed the problem. Page a.aspx does not have to reload because there is no postback value and instead follows the url to b.aspx.

Comment: -1 for providing an answer unlikely to help anyone else. This specific thingy may have helped your particular problem but it does not give a clear insight into why a page might take a long time to reach init.

Comment: I think the lesson to be learned here is that if you PostBack data to the page expect that page to reload.  I was showing there is a better way to handle opening links from charts that won't PostBack using the url to pass the value via GET instead. @AZ can you think of a way I can edit to make more useful?

Comment: you have too options here: 1. reword your question title (and body) and make it clear it's about redirects between pages and not simply about page init. 2. provide another answer that actually answers the question as it's stated or close your own question.

Comment: in it's current form you have a question about why might Init take a long time to reach on a specific page with an answer that talks about postbacks on another page. I get that they are connected in your particular case but for anybody else stumbling on this.... Imagine yourself googling on a page_Init question and getting to this. Would it have any sense or value?